# PubChem database into mysql

Tags: mysql, database, pubchem

I want to download the [pubchem substance database](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) and put all information into a MySQL database. Is this possible, and if so how?

Is there a script which automatically update the database?

Comment: What format is the database in? Can you show an example entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is available on the PubChem FTP site:
    ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/

Answer (score 1):

The PubChem [download page](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pc_fetch/pc_fetch-help.html) makes it clear that you can download the results from **specific** searches in several formats.

It does not seem like there is a way for you to download the entire database. If you want a copy of their entire database, try contacting the helpdesk: info@ncbi.nlm.nih.gov